# Use of logs in a regression analysis

Tags: regression, data-transformation, least-squares

I'm doing a paper on the impact of FDI on GDP and unemployment in different countries and I'm doing an OLS regression analysis for my data.

Would it make sense to use logs for only one variable? Or is it necessary to use logs on all variables?

Since my data is in USD, the numbers are quite large and has a skewed distribution.